# mutually exclusive sets closed under addition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

I was wondering if it is possible to find, or prove the existence of two sets S and S', both subsets of the natural numbers, that are mutually exclusive and respectively closed under addition. An example would be the trivial solution {0}, and all other numbers that are not zero. These sets are mutually exclusive and closed under addition.

Can anyone prove the existence/provide an example of/ disprove the existence of two nontrivial, mutually exclusive subsets of the natural numbers, or lead me to resources that help me further my knowledge?

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** Assume $S$ contains a positive integer $m$ and $S'$ contains a positive integer $n$.  Show that (using closure under addition) $S$ and $S'$ have a common element.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  The problem does not require that $1$ belongs to either $S$ or $S'$.

Comment: @hardmath I had considered letting the sets be multiples of two relatively prime numbers a and b respectively, only to realize that ab belongs to both sets. Now I see, thanks to the answer how to generalize this to all possible sets. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't **explicitly** exclude the empty set, then the problem is trivial. Currenly you have not excluded this case.

Comment: I did not exclude trivial cases in the problems. However the question explicitly ("nontrivial  mutually exclusive") asks for nontrivial solutions to the problem. I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both subset don't have $0$. Because the two subsets $S_1,S_2$ are closed under addition, we have that they contain all products of their minimal elements. Let $a$ be the smallest element in $S_1$ and $b$ be the smallest element in $S_2$ then $aN=\{a,2a,3a...\} \subset S_1$ and $bN=\{b,2b,3b,...\} \subset S_2$. So then $S_1,S_2$ must both have $ab$.